# navigation service navigation pivot error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, navigation, pivot

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?pivott.SelectedIndex = 0", UriKind.Relative));
```

I am using this code for navigate my pivot index=0 and it works for once. when I call for the second, my programme stops.not exit but stops. what can the reason of this be? how can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying up to. But i understand that the situation is to change the pivot index to 1 when you are navigating. Ok i will you for dynamically select the pivot index.

In mainpage from where i would be navigating to Sample.xaml:

`NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Sample.xaml?id=1", UriKind.Relative));`

In Sample.xaml put this code:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        string index;
        int number=0;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("id", out index))
        {
            if (Int32.TryParse(index, out number))
            {
                PivotItem.SelectedIndex = number;
            }
        }
    }
```

Change the index value by changing the id value at main page.

Comment: according to 5.2.4.1, I have some problems about device back button. I have a pivot on my app and has 2 child. index 0 and 1. somewhere, my app switch to device own sms sending component,and then when user press the back button, it returns to my app and wait to the pivot index 1.microsoft didnT accept it. so, I am using navigate pivot for jumping pivot index 0 (at the beginning of the app).the code works for once, but for the second, it doesn't work. your code is not work for me.

Comment: When you are in main page the app should exit when the user presses back button. When the user presses back button on sms service on phone, it would obviously return to app and the code you want to write should be launcher completed event. I will rewrite the code once.And attach some more details about the failed report in your question. otherwise it is difficult to decipher what you are trying